# Why does printf literally print (null) and what exactly happens?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

in a C programming exercise I'm doing something like this (just simplifying):

```
printf( "%s", 0);
```

The output is

```
(null)
```

What happens here? I assume that `printf` interprets the zero as a `char *`, so to `NULL`?
How could I replicate this result by something like

```
char string[] = NULL; //compiler-error
printf( "%s", string);
```

?

Comment: `null; //compiler-error` the constant is defined as upper-case, and C is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, I did type 'NULL', only mistyped here...

Comment: I accepted AnT's answer, since technically speaking, it completely answers my question - although the comment discussion in Greg Hewgill's answer helped at least as much...

Comment: Please, don't use an array, just change to `char *string = NULL;`.  That would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, your

```
printf("%s", 0);
```

leads to undefined behavior (UB). `%s` in `printf` requires a `char *` pointer as argument. You are passing `0`, which is an `int`. That alone already breaks your code, just like

```
printf("%s", 42);
```

would. For that specific UB the fact that `0` is a *zero* does not make any difference.

Secondly, if you really want to attempt to pass a null-ponter to `%s` format specifier, you have to do something like

```
printf("%s", (char *) 0);
```

Of course, this leads to undefined behavior as well, since `%s` requires a pointer to a valid string as argument, and `(char *) 0` is not a valid string pointer. But some implementations prefer to handle such situations gracefully and just print `(null)`.

In your particular case you just got lucky: `printf("%s", 0)` "worked" the same way as `printf("%s", (char *) 0)` would and your implementation saved the day by outputting `(null)`.

Comment: By 'undefined behavior', one usually means 'undefined by the standards' right?
Just asking, because the printf-source somehow interprets the zero pointer and prints out `(null)` ( so in the printf-source, the behavior is specified, which was the point of this comment-question).

Comment: Yes, undefined by the standard, meaning implementations (compilers, standard library sources, etc.) can do what they like as long as it is not explicitly ruled out by the wording of the standard.

Comment: In practice, due to that lack of guaranteed outcome, UB usually screams 'Really don't do this!'

Comment: @polynomial_donut: If invoking UB, prepare for [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). In other words: **do avoid at all costs**

Comment: @chux: Form the very pedantic point of view, `%s` requires a pointer to the beginning of a *string*. *String* is a formal term in C defined in 7.1.1 as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". The reason the spec of `s` specifier in `printf` does not use the term *string* is that it also has to cover such cases as `%42s`, which do not require null character termination. But pure `%s` requires a null terminator, which allows us to describe its argument as a pointer to a *string*.

Comment: @Olaf: I don't think I wanted to make use of any UB, but thanks for emphasizing :) I don't want nasal demons :(

Comment: @underscore_d nothing is explicitly ruled out when UB happens

Comment: @MattMcNabb Guess it wasn't clear enough: that's exactly what I meant. If the standard doesn't explicitly state what should happen in a scenario = that thing is UB = anything can happen.

Comment: @underscore_d you said "can do what they like **as long as...**." However there is , in fact, no "as long as": they can do what they like, full stop.

Comment: No, the "as long as" is the key condition: they can do what they want _if the outcome of the situation is not defined by the standard_. If, however, it _is_, they _cannot_. (If I've finally explained my wording well enough, perhaps we can delete these.)

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, passing a null pointer to `printf %s` is not guaranteed to do anything.  Everything else being equal, we would expect a segmentation violation or other ungraceful crash, as `printf` attempts to dereference the null pointer.  As a convenience, however, many (most?) implementations of `printf` have, somewhere deep within them, the equivalent of

```
case 's':
    char *p = va_arg(argp, char *);
    if(p == NULL) p = "(null)";
    fputs(p, stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using something like:

```
char *string = NULL;

printf("%s", string);
```

Many implementations of `printf()` will print `(null)` or something similar when passed a `NULL` pointer to `%s`. But they don't have to do that (it's not required by the standard).

Comment: I haven't tried, but "suspected" this would (partly) work. But what I was wondering: Going about it the way you propose, do I risk a segfault, because there is no guarantee for `printf` to encounter a terminating '\0'-character?

Comment: @polynomial_donut: This doesn't have anything to do with terminating '\0' characters, because a `NULL` pointer doesn't point to anything at all.

Comment: Oh I see... and `(null)` is the string interpretation of `NULL` defined in `printf`?

Comment: @polynomial_donut: Right. The behaviour of printing `(null)` is a convenience for the programmer, provided by some (or most) implementations of `printf()`. It's a convenience because printing *something* is often a lot more helpful than simply crashing.

Comment: @GregHewgill: On the other hand, I might argue that crashing would be better. Code that passes `NULL` to `printf` when it needs a pointer to a string is buggy. I'd rather catch that bug as early as possible. A stray `"(null)"` in a program's output is too easy to miss.

Comment: I also found the fact, that '(null)' was printed rather confusing. A straight crash wouldn't have triggered my question, probably.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, passing 0 to `printf` results in undefined behavior because the format-specifier you have says it prints a string, but you gave it an int. To replicate, you can do this:

```
char *string = NULL;
printf("%s", string);
```

Comment: That's not the reason `(null)` is printed. If you were to pass `5` instead of `0` for example, it's still "looking for a string and didn't receive one", but the resulting behaviour will be quite different than printing `(null)`.

Comment: @Greg thanks, I edited my answer. You learn something new every day :)